# How to connect my third party application to a database

Tags: android, database

I have to develop an `android application` for the website http://202.53.81.30/olsnew/ The webpage consists of a login database. The website is under the control of my college. how could I connect with the login database from my `application`. Do I need to take `permissions` from the college to access the `login table` or is there any alternative?

Comment: May be You need a password and user id to access any database that is on Server.

Comment: my problem is similar to the third party application connecting to the facebook server... how do the developer can get the userid and password of the database...